# Finding the next document in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

If this is my collection structure:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("4fdbaf608b446b0477000142"), name: "product 1" }
{ _id: ObjectId("4fdbaf608b446b0477000143"), name: "product 2" }
{ _id: ObjectId("4fdbaf608b446b0477000144"), name: "product 3" }
```

and I query product 1, is there a way to query the next document, which in this case would be "product 2"?

Comment: So you want to query for the first document after "product 1"?  How are you defining the documents' order (what's considered 'after')?

Comment: I have not reordered them at all, they are in the original insertion order. The way I got product 1 is someone goes to testsite.com/4fdbaf608b446b0477000142 I take the number and query by id.

Answer (score 25):

It is best to add explicit `sort()` criteria if you want a predictable order of results.

Assuming the order you are after is "insertion order" and you are using MongoDB's default generated ObjectIds, then you can query based on the ObjectId:

```
// Find next product created
db.products.find({_id: {$gt: ObjectId("4fdbaf608b446b0477000142") }}).limit(1)
```

Note that this example only works because:

- the first four bytes of the ObjectId are calculated from a unix-style timestamp (see: [ObjectId Specification](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification))
- a query on `_id` alone will use the default `_id` index (sorted by id) to find a match

So really, this implicit sort is the same as:

```
db.products.find({_id: {$gt: ObjectId("4fdbaf608b446b0477000142" )}}).sort({_id:1}).limit(1);
```

If you added more criteria to the query to qualify how to find the "next" product (for example, a `category`), the query could use a different index and the order may not be as you expect.

You can check index usage with [explain()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain).

Answer (score 1):

Starting in `Mongo 5`, it's a perfect use case for the new [`$setWindowFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/)  aggregation operator:

```javascript
// { _id: 1, name: "product 1" }
// { _id: 2, name: "product 2" }
// { _id: 3, name: "product 3" }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $setWindowFields: {
    sortBy: { _id: 1 },
    output: { next: { $push: "$$ROOT", window: { documents: [1, 1] } } }
  }}
])
// { _id: 1, name: "product 1", next: [{ _id: 2, name: "product 2" }] }
// { _id: 2, name: "product 2", next: [{ _id: 3, name: "product 3" }] }
// { _id: 3, name: "product 3", next: [ ] }
```

This:

- `$sort`s documents by their order of insertion using their `_id`s (`ObjectId`s contain the timestamp of insertion): `sortBy: { _id: 1 }`
- adds the `next` field in each document (`output: { running: { ... }}`)

  - by `$push`ing the whole document `$$ROOT` (`$push: "$$ROOT"`)
  - on a specified span of documents (the `window`) which is in this case is a range of only the next document document: `window: { documents: [1, 1] }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the items back in insertion order using ObjectId.  See: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimizing+Object+IDs#OptimizingObjectIDs

If you want to get them back in some other order then you will have to define what that order is and store more information in your documents.