# Next and previous documents

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I am making an image gallery. Each image has an _id and when I'm viewing an image I want the next 3 images and 3 before. How can I get this in a mongodb query? I think that I can use sort by _id because this is unsortable. Maybe with mapReduce or some specific query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding The Next Document in MongoDb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012253/finding-the-next-document-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can sort by `_id`.  Use two queries: one for the 3 before and one for the 3 after.

An example in python:

```
my_id = coll.find()[20]['_id']
coll.find({ '_id': {'$lt': my_id}}).sort([('_id', -1)]).limit(3)  # before
coll.find({ '_id': {'$gt': my_id}}).sort('_id').limit(3)  # after
```