# How to find previous id in mongodb

Tags: java, angularjs, mongodb, spring-mvc

In my web project, I have older and newer buttons. If I click on older it has to display previous blog details n vice versa for newer. Now I am passing current id in the backend and I have to search and find previous id in MongoDB. How to get that. If any links related to this please provide.

This is piece of code where I am taking current id:

**Controller.js**:

```
$scope.previousBeat = function(beatId){
                            var beatId = beatId;
                            blogService.getPreviousBlog(beatId, function(data){
                                $scope.blogId = data;
                            })
                        };
```

In **service.js**:

```
this.getPreviousBlog = function(id, callback){
    var url = 'blog/' + id + '/details';
    httpService.getRequest(url, callback);
};
```

In **controller.java**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/details", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Blog getPreviousBlogWithId(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        try {
            Blog blog = blogService.findBlogById(id);

            return blogService.incrementViewCount(blog);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log.error("Error while retrieving blog", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Service.java:

```
 @Override
    public Blog findBlogById(String id) {
        Blog blog = blogRepo.findOne(id);
        find().sort({_id:1})

        if (blog != null) {
            return blog;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Is there any way to get previous id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Next and previous documents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123483/next-and-previous-documents)

Answer (score 2):

If your collection records are sorted by `id` then you can write like this:

```
db.blog.find({_id: {$lt: priviousId}}).sort({_id: 1}).limit(1)[0];
```

Basically, we are sorting by `id` and then using `$lt` to sort over `_id` in your collection and getting only the first record. That will be your previous Blog.

In the Groovy code:

```
blogRepo.find(["_id": ["$lt": priviousId]]).sort(["_id": 1]).limit(1)[0];
```

Comment: ok..Thank u..And priviousId is which pass form front end right?

Comment: Yup, `priviousId` is one you are passing from front-end.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
 - Syntax error on token ")", invalid Expression
 - Syntax error, insert ":: IdentifierOrNew" to complete 
  ReferenceExpression
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
 - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to ..

Comment: Blog blog =blogRepo.find({_id: {$lt: priviousId}}).sort({_id: 1}).limit(1)[0];..This line oly

Comment: What is `blogRepo` and which is your collection? I assumed that `blogRepo` is your collection.

Comment: blogRepo is only my Collection..i  just assigned it blog variable so that return blog..

Comment: @Override
 public Blog findPreviousBlogById(String priviousId) {
  Blog blog = blogRepo.findOne(priviousId);
  blog.find({_id: {$lt: priviousId}}).sort({_id: 1}).limit(1)[0];
  //Blog blog =blogRepo.find({}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1);

  if (blog != null) {
   return blog;
  }
  return null;
 }

Comment: Sorry, I posted the answer as the Groovy/Mongo shell code. Please port it to work in Java. I think, you have to use the `BasicDBObject` class.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal `db.blog.find({_id: {$lt: priviousId}}).sort({_id: 1}).limit(1)[0];` will this query works? I think in `sort` `_id` would be `-1` to take the reverse order